# Layouts using neo4j and sigma.js

Tags: neo4j, sigma.js

I am trying to learn how to use sigma.js with neo4j and would appreciate some help in getting the layout algorithms to work with sigma.neo4j.cypher. The sigma.layout.fruchtermanReingold.js layout does not work in the code below when used with sigma.neo4j.cypher. I am pretty confident that I have all sigma imports but can add those to the question if you feel the issue might be there.

Many thanks.

```
<div id="container">
    <style>
        #graph-container {
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/worker.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/supervisor.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.plugins.animate/sigma.plugins.animate.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.fruchtermanReingold/sigma.layout.fruchtermanReingold.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

    sigma.neo4j.cypher(
            { url: 'http://localhost:7474', user: 'neo4j', password: 'admin' },
            'MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m LIMIT 100',
            { container: 'graph-container' } ,
            function(s) {
                console.log('Number of nodes :'+ s.graph.nodes().length);
                console.log('Number of edges :'+ s.graph.edges().length);
            }
    );

    // Configure the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm:
    var frListener = sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.configure(s, {
      maxIterations: 500,
      easing: 'quadraticInOut',
      duration: 800
    });

    // Bind the events:
    frListener.bind('start stop interpolate', function(e) {
      console.log(e.type);
    });

    // Start the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm:
    sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.start(s);


</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check the linkurious sigma variant for some insight? Checkout http://github.com/linkurious/linkurious.js

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's perhaps due to the init of  sigma instance by the cypher plugin. I will take a look at this

Comment: Thank you Logisima, Iet me know how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re,

I have done a plunkr demo here : http://embed.plnkr.co/daMtV25BYEh5ZQFG2fnk/preview

Now, I see a graph, but nothing mooving ... and the fruchtermanReingold example doesn't work on linkurious repo.

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks very useful, I will see if I can get it working with my own example.

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate Sigme outside of the Cypher plugin (which would instantiate a sigma object for you if you don't provide it).